# Force a redirect with Cloudflare on a GitLab hosted website?

Tags: gitlab, cloudflare

I have a site hosted on GitLab pages and using Cloudflare to manage the domain DNS, when I try to access the site using `mysite.com` it returns the website like it should, but when I enter `www.mysite.com` it returns an error 404 page from GitLab something like this [GitLab error 404 page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ga0T1.png)

I have tried to create page rules on Cloudflare but it's doesn't seem to have resolved the problem (yet), It's been over 10 hours, I have no idea how long this should take or if I am doing the right thing in the first place.